# Data about financing renewable energy

Tags: finance, energy

I am searching for data on financing renewables. The best case would be a data set with a split in private and public funding whereas private should be divided into equity and debt and the public into subsidies and credit.
Historic data or projections for 2030 targets are appreciated. Most interesting for me is Europe, but I am also interested in other data.

If you have any idea where to look or whom to ask, please let me know.